# Newly installed Win10 desktop build graphics goes blank when installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce, threadripper

We just built a Threadripper 1950x computer with 2x Nvidia GTX 1080ti GPUs with SLI. Windows 10 Pro x64 installed easily. When the desktop comes up, right away we installed the latest Nvidia graphics drivers from their website. During installation, the screen goes blank. One graphics card keeps the screen blank, while the other graphics card doesn't even register that anything is connected to the monitor. Using HDMI.

Restarted many times... So I go into safemode and uninstall the graphics driver, and other Nvidia programs that were automatically installed. Finally get back to a low-resolution desktop. This time I installed Geforce Experience to automatically install the graphics driver. But first, I installed TeamViewer so we can remotely log in.

Same problem again with graphics, goes blank. At least now I can remotely get into the computer... Tried uninstalling graphics and reinstalling, still no luck.

What can I do? The graphics card (at least one of them) is working fine with the default windows driver. Do the latest graphics drivers not work with Threadrippers? Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: “Do the latest graphics drivers not work with Threadrippers?” Your problem has nothing to do with your CPu

Comment: Can you successfully install the drivers with only one of the cards?  Can you try both cards one at a time?  This would verify that both cards work.  Do you have a big enough PSU for everything?  What motherboard do you have?

Comment: Try an older NVidia driver, say 6 months older. Sometimes older drivers work. And during the installation, only select the drivers and no addons.